# does not exists in the current context while creating menu c#

Tags: android, menu

I create an app in android api 10(2.3.5) c#. I use xml file `MainMenu` for menu.
I use this code for creating menu:

```
 public bool onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(Resource.Layout.MainMenu, menu);
            return true;
        }
```

But I get error `getMenuInflater()`.

please tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line to 
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
to
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();

Refer this tutorial too
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Sorry I tried MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater() But I get the same error. The link you said also describes the same syntax.My xml file 
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item
      android:id="@+id/option1"
      android:title="save"/>
  <item
      android:id="@+id/option2"
      android:title="delete"/>
  <item
      android:id="@+id/option3"
      android:title="edit"/>
  </menu>